# Anular condição PL-SQL

Tags: pl-sql

Possuo uma condição, como esta abaixo, em uma *query*.

Caso receba o parâmetro vazio ou com 0, gostaria que esta condição deixasse de existir, ou fosse anulada, para que a *query* busque todos os médicos.

```
where CD_MEDICO_CIRURGIAO = :medico
```

Como fazer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O certo seria você verificar antes se existe o código do médico (`:medico`) e ai sim inserir a condição.

Mas isso deve resolver, caso você não consiga pela primeira opção ([NVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm))

```
where CD_MEDICO_CIRURGIAO = NVL(:medico, CD_MEDICO_CIRURGIAO)
```

Comment: Teria um exemplo desta verificação, para ver se o parâmetro :medico recebe valores? Da outra forma que você citou abaixo não consegui, pois ela traz sempre todos os valores, e não é o que desejo.

Comment: não é isso que vc queria? se :medico for vazio trazer todos os médicos? Esse código vai trazer todos os médicos. Poste seu código que da para melhorar o exemplo.

Comment: select NR_CIRURGIA from cirurgia 
where CD_MEDICO_CIRURGIAO = :medico

Comment: Que linguagem você está usando? Posta o código que vai gerar essa saída, pois isso não parace PL/SQL puro. Outra coisa qual banco você está usando?

Comment: Isto é pl sql sim. E :medico é um parâmetro passado quando rodar o código. Se eu passar como parâmetro o código de um médico irá retornar corretamente os valores correspondentes ao código. O que eu preciso, é no caso de este parâmetro vir vazio, esta condição deixar de existir, para buscar todos  os valores.

Comment: Qual banco de dados? Oracle?

Comment: banco de dados oracle

Comment: Só para ter certeza mesmo, hehehe. Modifiquei a resposta.

Comment: Funciona bem, muito obrigado :D